# disable file permission when counter value reaches zero in pdf download counter

Tags: php

```
wp-downloadmanager.1.62 wordpress plugin
wp-downloadmanager.php  line no: 189            


     if(($file_permission > 0 
    && intval($current_user->
    wp_user_level) >= $file_permission && intval($user_ID) >   0)
    || ($file_permission == 0 && intval($user_ID) > 0) || $file_permission == -1)
    {
        $update_hits = $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->downloads SET file_hits = 
(file_hits - 1), 
        file_last_downloaded_date = '".current_time('timestamp')."' 
        WHERE file_id = $file_id AND file_permission != -2");
im trying something like this 


    if(($update_hits == 0))
   {
   $file_permission == 1;
    }
```

i was trying to get the output of : You do not have permission to download this file
    when counter values reaches to zero.
      i was trying to get the output of : You do not have permission to download this file
    when counter values reaches to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a select first to verify if the file_hits reached 0 ?

```
$file_hits = $wpdb->fetchOne("SELECT file_hits FROM $wpdb->downloads WHERE file_id = $file_id AND file_permission != -2");
if($file_hits == 0) {
    $file_permission == 1;
} else {
    // do your update here
}
```

Comment: if($file_hits == 0) {
    $file_permission == 1;   this functionality is not working friend which means file permission is not go to disable state